# Jquery .parent().attr().split(' ').pop() returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, split, parent-child

I want to detect second class "rpvItem2" from parent element of "rtsSelected". I have read different articles here but unable to fix this issue.

> The code works fine in my local PC html file. It is also working
> online but with console error.
>
> In console:
> **TypeError: $(...).parent(...).attr(...) is undefined**

My jQuery:

```
// window load BEGINS
$(window).load(function () {
    var getRtsSelected = $("ul.tabset ul.rtsUL").find(".rtsSelected");
    var testtabsetparent = $(getRtsSelected).parent('li').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    if (testtabsetparent != '') {
        $(".tab-content .tab-box #ContentPlaceHolder1_" + testtabsetparent + " iframe").addClass("content-loaded");
    }
});
// window load ENDS
```

My HTML:

```
<ul id="navtabs" class="tabset">
<li>
    <ul class="rtsUL">
        <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst rpvItem1">
            <a href="#" class="rtsLink rtsBefore">Item One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="rtsLI rpvItem2">
            <a href="#" class="rtsLink rtsSelected">Item Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Simple debugging should sort this. Use some dev tools, and figure out which thing is undefined. Start with the base object, then the parent, then attribute, then the split array, and then finally the pop result.

Comment: Don't use classes for that, use `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Probably your UL element or its content is loaded dynamically (or classes are set later) after the window load event has been fired. Your error means you are trying to call `pop()` on `undefined`, becasue you call `attr()` on empty set.

Comment: Works fine for me [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/07j18Ldd/).

Comment: Btw why you are using attr(), its deprecated use 'Prop()' instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var cls = $("ul.tabset ul.rtsUL").find(".rtsSelected").parent('li').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
        console.log(cls);
    });
```

will return

**rpvItem2**

Comment: BUT OP is using window load event, so it should really doesn't make any difference...

Comment: Currently it looks helpful "console.log(cls);"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    var getRtsSelected = $("ul.tabset ul.rtsUL").find(".rtsSelected");
    var testtabsetparent = $(getRtsSelected).parent('li').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    if (testtabsetparent != '') {
        $(".tab-content .tab-box #ContentPlaceHolder1_" + testtabsetparent + " iframe").addClass("content-loaded");
    }
});
```

```html
<ul id="navtabs" class="tabset">
<li>
    <ul class="rtsUL">
        <li class="rtsLI rtsFirst rpvItem1">
            <a href="#" class="rtsLink rtsBefore">Item One</a>
        </li>
        <li class="rtsLI rpvItem2">
            <a href="#" class="rtsLink rtsSelected">Item Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I test this code and this is working. May be you are using old version of `jquery`